# Recursion of template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

```
template <class T> class circuit{
private:
    vector<T> components;
    string type;
public: 
    complex<double> getImpedance();
};


complex<double> circuit<circuitComponent>::getImpedance() {
// function to calculate impedance in trivial case of components all in series/parallel
}


complex<double> circuit<circuit>::getImpedance() {}
```

I'm trying to write a program that will be able to calulate the (complex) impedance of an arbitrary circuit of resistors, capacitors, and inductors.

For a circuit in which all the components are in series/parallel with one another, this is trivial. However, this isn't generally true. For more complex circuits with a mixture of series and parallel components, I want to be able to describe the circuit as a collection of circuits (i.e. sub-circuits/nested circuits).

So, I'm trying to write a class for circuits that can contain a vector of components, *or* a vector of circuits. I have attempted to write a template class to do this, but when I try to define the getImpedance() function for the case of a circuit of circuits (which I was planning on doing recursively), I get an error because the compiler doesn't know what type to give the sub-circuits (i.e. in circuit, the inner circuit doesn't have a known type).

So, my question is, is there a way to recursively provide template arguments?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Will

EDIT: My complete code so far is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include<complex>
using namespace std;

// Declare pi as const. 
const double pi(3.1415927);

// A class for general circuit components. 
class circuitComponent {
protected:
    // The component type, its impedance, and the frequency of the AC current passing through it. 
    string componentType;
    complex<double> impedance;
    double frequency;
public:
    circuitComponent(string compName, complex<double> imp, double freq) : componentType(compName), impedance(imp), frequency(freq) {}
    virtual ~circuitComponent() {};
    virtual void setImpedance(const complex<double>&) = 0;
    // Functions to return the impedance and the frequency. 
    virtual complex<double> getImpedance() = 0;
    virtual double getFrequency() = 0;
};

// A class for resistors, derived from circuitComponent. 
class resistor : public circuitComponent{
protected: 
    double resistance;
public:
    resistor() : circuitComponent("resistor",complex<double>(0,0), 0), resistance(0) {}
    resistor(double res, double freq) : circuitComponent("resistor", complex<double>(res, 0), freq), resistance(res) {}
    ~resistor() {}
    // A function to set the impedance of the component. Also alters the resistance accordingly. 
    void setImpedance(const complex<double>& imp){ 
        // Deals with case of non-pure-real impedance assignment. 
        if (imp.imag() != 0){
            cerr << "Cannot assign impedance with non-zero imaginary component to a resistor." << endl;
        }
        else {
            resistance = imp.real(); impedance = resistance;
        }
    }
    // Functions to return the impedace and the frequency of the resistance. 
    complex<double> getImpedance() { return impedance; }
    double getFrequency() { return frequency; }
};

// A class for capacitors.
class capacitor : public circuitComponent{
private:
    double capacitance;
public:
    capacitor() : circuitComponent("capacitor", complex<double>(0, 0), 0), capacitance(0) {}
    capacitor(double cap, double freq) : circuitComponent("capacitor", complex<double>(0, -1 / (2.0*pi*frequency*cap)), freq), capacitance(cap) {}
    ~capacitor() {}
    void setImpedance(const complex<double>& imp){ 
        if (imp.real() != 0){
            cerr << "Cannot assgn impedance with non-zero real component to a capacitor." << endl;
        }
        else{
            impedance = imp; capacitance = imp.imag(); // THIS IS INCORRECT
        }
    }
    complex<double> getImpedance() { return impedance; }
    double getFrequency() { return frequency; }
};

// A class for inductors.
class inductor : public circuitComponent{
private:
    double inductance;
public:
    inductor() : circuitComponent("inductor", complex<double>(0, 0), 0), inductance(0) {}
    inductor(double ind, double freq) : circuitComponent("inductor", complex<double>(0,2*pi*frequency*ind), freq), inductance(ind) {}
    ~inductor() {}
    void setImpedance(const complex<double>& imp){
        if (imp.real() != 0){
            cerr << "Cannot assign impedance with non-zero real component to an inductor." << endl;
        }
        else{
            impedance = imp; inductance = imp.imag(); // THIS IS INCORRECT
        }
    }
    complex<double> getImpedance() { return impedance; }
    double getFrequency() { return frequency; }
};


template <class T> class circuit{
private:
    vector<T> components;
    string type;
public: 
    complex<double> getImpedance();
};

// For the case where the circuit (or sub-circuit) has no subcircuits, and hence is a collection of components that are ALL in parallel/series with one another. 
complex<double> circuit<circuitComponent>::getImpedance() {
    complex<double> impedance(0);
    vector<circuitComponent>::iterator componentIter;
    if (type == "s"){
        for (componentIter = components.begin(); componentIter != components.end(); ++componentIter){
            impedance += componentIter->getImpedance();
        }
    }
    else if (type == "p") {
        complex<double> reciprocolImpedance(0);
        for (componentIter = components.begin(); componentIter != components.end(); ++componentIter){
            // complex<double>(1,0) is just the number 1 expressed as a complex number. 
            reciprocolImpedance += (complex<double>(1,0)/componentIter->getImpedance());
        }
        impedance = (complex<double>(1, 0)) / reciprocolImpedance;
    }
    return impedance;   
}

// THIS is the problem line. 
complex<double> circuit<circuit>::getImpedance() {}




int main(){


    string exitStr;
    cin >> exitStr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete..Please post complete code...and also describe what you want

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You should remember that `circuit` is a template class; so you can't write something as

```
complex<double> circuit<circuit>::getImpedance() {}
```

beacuse (1) lacks of `template <>` before and (2) lacks of template parameter in the inner `circuit`.

A way to write `getImpedance` is to write a generic version, by example

```
template <typename T>
std::complex<double> circuit<T>::getImpedance()
 { return components.size() ? components[0].getImpedance() : 1.0; }
```

and a specialized version for `circuitComponent`, by example

```
template <>
std::complex<double> circuit<circuitComponent>::getImpedance()
 { return components.size() ? components[0].val : 0.0; }
```

A full working example

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

struct circuitComponent
 { std::complex<double> val; };

template <typename T>
class circuit
 {
   private:
      std::vector<T> components;
      std::string type;

   public: 
      std::complex<double> getImpedance();
 };

template <>
std::complex<double> circuit<circuitComponent>::getImpedance()
 { return components.size() ? components[0].val : 0.0; }


template <typename T>
std::complex<double> circuit<T>::getImpedance()
 { return components.size() ? components[0].getImpedance() : 1.0; }

int main ()
 {
   circuit<circuitComponent>  c0;

   std::cout << c0.getImpedance() << std::endl;

   circuit<circuit<circuitComponent>>  c1;

   std::cout << c1.getImpedance() << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: That's perfect, very helpful! Thanks a lot.